# React handlechange is only updating each letter and input is not realizing it

Tags: reactjs

Ok, I give up, need help.

Done this on many projects before, but can't seem to figure out why my state isn't behaving correctly.  Here is the following code bit that matters.  The problem is that it changes state, but only to the last letter that was entered.  And it doesn't reflect in the input box (it stays blank)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class PublicMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
    };
  
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    let center = this.olmap.getView().getCenter();
    let zoom = this.olmap.getView().getZoom();
    if (center === nextState.center && zoom === nextState.zoom) return false;
    return true;
  }


  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div
          id="map"
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "360px" }}
          className="container"
        >
          <br></br>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
            onClick={(e) => this.userAction()}
          >
            Draw New Polygon
          </button>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            name="name"
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={this.addName}
            className="btn btn-primary"
          >
            Add Name
          </button>

          <br></br>
          <br></br>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default PublicMap;
```

EDIT:  I added all the relevant code *I believe
EDIT**: I don't believe the shouldComponentUpdate() would matter, but left it in just in case it did, the code relates to something else.

Example of what my problem is.
typing in the input box shows nothing in the box, totally blank.

checking the component or console logging the

handlechange(e){ console.log(e.target.value)} // output is just the single letter

I'm sort of stuck because I've used this formula everywhere else in my project and cant figure out why this bug exists.

Comment: This doesn't look wrong. Could you provide a runnable example where this is happening?

Comment: Your problem its exactly on shouldComponentUpdate. If you set it to always return true, then your component will update. So, your if inside it is interfering, you need to check that logic.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

ok, as pointed out by LPP in the comments, the shouldComponentUpdate was throwing it off.  refactored the logic and it works now.  Thanks all.